# Nested list in python won't format through Lambda, I am struggling to understand why

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling to get the below code to work, I have formatted a table so the output looks better, but I am trying to be able to sort the data by each index in the list. I have played around with a menu to choose one of the lambda options, but the output always appears to be the same. I've taken the menu out for now until I can figure out why it's not formatting correctly.

```py
master_list = [['A53745678', "Charles", 3, 'SOM993'], ['A34345678', "Charles Lob Miester Twidde To", 4, 'SOM555'],
               ['A54345678', "Tob", 9, 'SOM363'], ['A01245678', "Pob", 10, 'SOM754'], ['A98745678', "Cob", 3, 'SOM343'],
               ['A64345678', "Fob", 2, 'SOM098'], ['A84245678', "Bob", 1, 'SOM343'], ['A84245678', "Fred", 9, 'SOM999'],
               ['A12345678', "Alex", 9, 'SOM111']]

def table():
    print("", item[0], " " * (9 - len(item[0])), ":", item[1], " " * (30 - len(item[1])), ":", item[2],
              " " * (2 - len(str(item[2]))), ":", item[3], " " * (2 - len(item[3])))

print(
        f"{'-' * 60}\n{' ' * 20}2021 STUDENT CLASS\n{'-' * 60}")
print(f" Student ID | Student Name {' ' * 19}Grade | Course Code")

for item in master_list: # student ID sorter
    table()
    master_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

for item in master_list: # Student name sorter
    table()
    master_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

for item in master_list: # Student Grade Sorter (need to reverse)
    table()
    master_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])

for item in master_list: # Sorting by course code
    table()
    master_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])
```

Comment: can you post the desired output please? Also is your code indented properly for `def table()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

You are sorting the list *after* the first row has been printed. Not only does this potentially result in the wrong row being displayed first (whichever row is at the head of the list), but it can lead to a duplicate row being printed because the list has been changed within the loop. Example:

```
>>> l = [2, 1]
>>> for i in l:
...     print(i)
...     l.sort()
... 
2
2
```

Here you see that `2` is printed twice - once because it is the first item in the list, then second because after the sort it is now the second item. There is also the inefficiency of repetitively re-sorting an already sorted list.

A better approach is to sort once before the loop is entered:

```
for item in sorted(master_list, key=lambda x: x[0]):    # student ID sorter
    table()
```

Using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) does not modify the original list. So if you are actually attempting a multikey sort (by relying on the cumulative affect of each stable sort) then you should sort once before each table dump:

```
master_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])     # student ID key
for item in master_list:
    table()

master_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])     # student name key
for item in master_list:
    table()

# etc. for additional keys
```

Another issue is the use of a global variable `item` in function `table()`. It's better to pass the item (row of data in this case) to the function, and to use a more descriptive name for the function:

```
def print_row(row):
    ...

for item in sorted(master_list, key=lambda x: x[0]):    # student ID sorter
    print_row(item)
```

You could also look at the string formatting directives that can be used to specify field widths. Instead of calculating the number of spaces required to pad out fields, you can do something like this:

```
def print_row(row):
    print(f' {row[0]:9}  : {row[1]:30}  :{row[2]:2}   : {row[3]}')
```

This uses a fstring with field widths to format the output.

Finally, why not have a function that prints the whole table in one go?:

```
def print_table(table):
    print(f"{'-' * 60}\n{' ' * 20}2021 STUDENT CLASS\n{'-' * 60}")
    print(f" Student ID | Student Name {' ' * 19}Grade | Course Code")
    for row in table:
        print(f' {row[0]:9}  : {row[1]:30}  :{row[2]:2}   : {row[3]}')
```